# Importhtml transpose formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import data with the importhtml function into a specific format within google sheets. Below I have an example of what the original import looks like and I am trying to format it to look like the 2nd example. Is that possible where each date has it's own column with the event to the right of it?

The tricky part is this list will auto update every week with new events so aggregating the correct dates/times into their own columns with the correct events... don't think it's possible with the widget I’m extracting from but if anyone has any ideas would greatly appreciate the suggestions.

If this works I’ll be using it to create a synced calendar with google/apple.

Here is the formula I am using: `=importhtml("https://sslecal2.investing.com?columns=exc&importance=2,3&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1","table","1")`

And here is the link to the spreadsheet if you need it

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IC_ZqKbLgMLksCXral5eXZcSf6CVDtTSsBxMNmbrhzo/edit?usp=sharing

[image: 1st Example]

[image: 2nd Example]

Comment: Images are not helpful, as the volunteer contributors here cannot access the data from them to even start. We also don't know sheet names, layout restrictions, data types, etc.—all of which are crucial in assessment and development. However, what you are asking, while it can be done, really goes beyond what a free, volunteer-run forum like this is designed to offer. That is, what you need is a custom, time-intensive, expert-level solution (i.e. real work), for which people generally need to hire someone. The bare minimum starting point will be to share a link to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the columns as a result of the import and in blank cells use

```
={TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 1),,1)),TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 1),,2))}
```

Share the link of the sheet so we can help you better